# Currently using C# and having trouble looping

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am currently having trouble looping the following code so that the `else` part asks the question again.

```
String name, wtd, act, trav;        
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, What do you want to do today?", name);
Console.WriteLine("1) Action\n2) Chilling\n3) Danger\n4) Good Food\n");
int result, ppl;
result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (result == 1)
{
    wtd = "action";
    act = "Stock Car Racing";
}
else if (result == 2)
{
    wtd = "chilling";
    act = "Hiking";
}
else if (result == 3)
{
    wtd = "danger";
    act = "Skydiving";
}
else if (result == 4)
{
    wtd = "good food";
    act = "to Taco Bell";
}
else
{
    wtd = "";
    act = "";
    Console.WriteLine("I do not understand. Please select again");
}
Console.WriteLine("Okay. If you are in the mood for " + wtd + ", then you should go " + act + "and travel in " + trav +".");
```

*The rest of the code works fine. `trav` variable works fine

I have tried using while loop, but it always comes back with errors, or does not run how i want it to. One of the most common errors when using the while loop are "**use of unassigned local variable `wtd`**" and "**use of unassigned local variable `act`**". These errors happen at the last `Console.WriteLine` part of the code.

I also need the variables to be defined based on used input and would like it to loop if there is any invalid input, like any other value besides the ones listed (1,2,3,4).

Comment: The compiler should be smart enough to see that the variable(s) are already assigned with a value. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tried to compiled by others.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use a `while` loop to keep asking for input until it is correct.

Something like this should work:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int ppl;
while (result < 1 && result > 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I do not understand. Please select again");
    result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

As for the error you are experiencing "use of unassigned local variable wtd" simply means that the variable may not have a value assigned to it when you try to print at the end. This is fixed by simply initializing the value when you declare the value at the top:

```
String name = "", wtd = "", act = "", trav = "";
```

Comment: Note to op, you should never use `Convert.ToInt32` to parse user input, the program crashes on the most simple mistake, its always better to use the `TryParse` methods

Comment: the condition is wrong. it should be `while (result <1 || result >4)`

Answer (score 0):

For unassigned local variable messages, if you declared variables outside the loop and you just used them inside the loop, unassigned local variable information messages will appear, it won't break the application, it's just telling you that you didn't use the variable in the current scope. This is a good feature that will help you clean up your code from unused variables.

as for your code, you can do it like this :

```
string name = string.Empty, wtd = string.Empty, act = string.Empty, trav = string.Empty;
int result = 0, ppl = 0;
bool isTrue = true;
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, What do you want to do today?", name);
while (isTrue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1) Action\n2) Chilling\n3) Danger\n4) Good Food\n");
    var isValidInt = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
    if(isValidInt)
    {
        if (result == 1)
        {
            wtd = "action";
            act = "Stock Car Racing";
            isTrue = false;
        }
        else if (result == 2)
        {
            wtd = "chilling";
            act = "Hiking";
            isTrue = false;
        }
        else if (result == 3)
        {
            wtd = "danger";
            act = "Skydiving";
            isTrue = false;
        }
        else if (result == 4)
        {
            wtd = "good food";
            act = "to Taco Bell";
            isTrue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            wtd = "";
            act = "";
            Console.WriteLine("I do not understand. Please select again");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Use numbers only");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Okay. If you are in the mood for " + wtd + ", then you should go " + act + "and travel in " + trav + ".");
```

The `isTrue` variable will tell the loop to continue looping, so for instance, if the user input `1`, it'll set the variable to false, to end the loop, if the user input any numbers larger than 4, it'll just keep it inside the loop and it'll start over again.

I've also replaced this line `result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` with this `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);` you should always use TryParse instead of converting the integers directly. the `TryParse` will check the string, if is it a valid integers, then will parse it, and it'll return true (as it's an integer) and the out will be the parsed integer. if the parse failed, it'll return false.

This way, you'll ensure you only get integers.

Comment: You could have made it simpler using `break`.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef, If is it for me, i'll use break, but since it's on public, I saw it'll be better to do it this way, so I can avoid `while(true)` so it will be more understandable for the loop logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Int32.TryParse` to confirm the input is a valid int. By using `do while` you can check the number is between 1 and 4, inclusive. I also recommend using `switch` instead of `if elseif`.

```
int result, ppl;
String name, wtd, act, trav;        
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, What do you want to do today?", name);
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1) Action\n2) Chilling\n3) Danger\n4) Good Food\n");
    Console.WriteLine("I do not understand. Please select again");
} while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) || result < 1 || result > 4)
switch (result)
{
    case 1:
        wtd = "action";
        act = "Stock Car Racing";
        break;
    case 2:
        wtd = "chilling";
        act = "Hiking";
        break;
    case 3:
        wtd = "danger";
        act = "Skydiving";
        break;
    case 4:
        wtd = "good food";
        act = "to Taco Bell";
        break;
    default:
        wtd = act = "";
}
Console.WriteLine("Okay. If you are in the mood for " + wtd + ", then you should go " + act + "and travel in " + trav +".");
```